# How to instantiate an object to another class in the constructor of a class? C++

Tags: c++, oop

Is it possible to construct an object to class2 in the constructor of class1 that can be used in all the functions in class1?

EXAMPLE:

```
class c1 {

//Constructor for c1
c1() {

//Object to class c2 that I want to be able to use in all the c1 functions
c2 c2Object;

}

void randomFunction() {

c2Object.randomFunctioninC2();

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a *member variable*. Notice that the variable is declared in the class itself, *not* in the constructor. If it was declared in the constructor, it would be an ordinary local variable in the constructor (and therefore it would only exist inside the constructor).

```
class c1 {
    c2 c2Object;

    void randomFunction() {
        c2Object.randomFunctioninC2();
    }
};
```

Comment: Basic question, but if I am using a header file, where do I declare the member variable?

Comment: @ryan In the class itself, so in the header file. Only member functions/constructors/destructors and static member variables can have separate declarations and definitions.

Comment: I have done the following and get all sorts of error.
http://i.imgur.com/4GyfCWL.png

Comment: I included all the header files I have

Comment: @ryan Then post the code that doesn't work (in a new question, since you're asking something different)